# C++ error: expected primary-expression before 'int'

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, codeblocks, symbol-table

I am trying to create a symbol table based on input from a file.

As of now, I have the code to read the file line-by-line, separate the tokens, and print out the token and its type.

Now, I have to find a way to store these values (token and type) into a symbol table.

I am not familiar with C++ **AT ALL**. I originally tried to make a multi-dimensional array, but this was a bust because I do no know the amount of lines or tokens a file will have and I could not dynamically set the size of the arrays. Now, I have decided to use a vector of vectors. This is what my line of code looks like:

```
vector< vector<int> > vec(4, vector<int>(4)) myVector;
```

I have no idea why it is not working. I copied it exactly from an answer on cplusplus.com. I have also tried

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > row;
```

which was taken from another SO question. I have been searching for hours for the best way to create this table and have run into nothing but problems.

The error I keep getting (as stated in the question) is

```
error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to figure out how you want your object to be called.

If you want to call your object `vec`, you should write:

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > vec(4, std::vector<int>(4));
```

If you want to call your object `myVector`, you should write:

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > myvector(4, std::vector<int>(4));
```

And if you have "using namespace std;" appearing anywhere in your code, [remove it, and forget that you ever saw anything like that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-in-c-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: Thank you!! This solved my problem. Also, I hadn't realized I needed to add `#include <vector>` at the top.